# Breadcrumbs in tcltk GUI

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to develop a UI in tcltk. Is there any way to introduce breadcrumbs into the UI?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A breadcrumbs widget is merely a row of buttons. What is your precise problem then?

Comment: A tweaked (i.e., read-only) text widget might be easier; the text's tags could be used to make the bits and pieces into hypertext, and would give a fairly clean effect.  (OTOH, it's a breadcrumb system; I always turn those off in my IDE where possible because I've never liked them.)

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion. I combined different text widgets having different page name and added necessary tag to them. It worked. Thanks again!